# how to get Aws instance name and port while deploying spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Can any one help me to get AWS application environment properties like instance name, id and port etc., after deploying using spring boot. i have a requirement like need to run one specific scenario to only one instance. i never know instance name until to deploy to read from local property file / yml file.

if you provide any example it would be help to me to understand more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, other than dumping a question here?

Comment: i dont have basic idea to implement regarding AWS. i am sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Typically AWS provides the metadata of an instance by issuing `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/`command inside the instance. In Spring Boot you can use`environment` variable.
Here is a [guide](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_enabling_instance_metadata_support_in_spring_boot) on how to do that.